# Debugger opens .ts file if server started from terminal but opens .js files if server started with docker-compose

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, vscode-debugger

My problem is that when I put a `debugger;` statement in my code, if I start my NestJS app from my terminal with `npm run start:debug`, the debugger will pause in the corresponding `.ts` file, but if I start the server from a `docker-compose.yml`, the debugger will pause in the built `.js` file, not is the `.ts` file.

To reproduce a minimal example, I have started a new NestJS project from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/)

```
git clone https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter.git projet
cd project
npm run install
```

I have then added the following `.vscode/launch.json`

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach NestJS",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I have updated `app.service.ts` to the following (I've added `debugger;`)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    debugger;

    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

If I run `npm run start:debug`, attach the debugger with my `AttachNestJS` configuration, and go to http://localhost:3000/, the debugger stops in `src/app.service.ts`.

Now, if I create a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14.18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package-lock.json package.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

A `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:debug:docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '8000:3000'
      - '9229:9229'
```

A `.dockerignore`

```
node_modules
.git
dist
```

And update the debug start command in scripts so the debugger will bind to the container

```
"start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
"start:debug:docker": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch",
```

And then run `docker-compose up --build`, the server starts, I can attach the debugger, and if I go to http://localhost:8000/, the debugger stops not in `src/app.service.ts`, but in `app.service.js`.

Note that I need to explicitly write `debugger;` in the file so that it stops, setting a breakpoint will result in "Unbound breakpoint".

Since the debugger correctly stops in `.ts` files when the server is run outside of docker, I don't think there is an issue with my typescript configuration, which is the one that comes out of the box after cloning the NestJS repo.

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/JeremyRippert/nest-js-debugger-repro) for this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTLAcLSu1Rw) which shows a solution to my problem.

The key was to add `"remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",` in my configuration in `launch.json`, `/usr/src/app` being what's next to `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` in the dockerfile